# Streaming replication in PostgreSQL 9.4

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, postgresql-9.4, failover

We have recently setup streaming replication in our Postgres server (t01, t02). 
t01 is master and t02 is the slave. I want to understand the below two issues:

1. Recently our `/var` directory of t01 server got full and app team was not able to access the application. My understanding was if t01 `/var` was full, the connection should be made to t02 and application should start using that as t02 `/var` was not full.
2. If we shutdown t01 server, will my application automatically use the t02 databases, Streaming replication will provide HA in this case or not?

Comment: This question is an off-topic on SO. Ask it on dba.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, PostgreSQL won't failover to the standby. Configuring failover properly is a hard problem, and you need specialized cluster software like Patroni to handle that.

As it is, you will have to fail over manually by running `pg_ctl promote` on the standby to do it.

You will also have to configure your clients to use the new server. To avoid that, you could use a virtual IP address that you can move to the standby, or you have to setup the clients to try both servers.